# Initialize data.table with heterogeneous types

Tags: r, data.table

I need to build a big `data.table` where every row is a user and columns are attributes of different types. I need to fill the table row by row. How should I initialize it?

For instance, if I do this:

```
dt.hetero <- data.table(matrix(-1, nrow=3, ncol=6))
names(dt.hetero) <- c("name", "lastname", "city", "age", "weight", "heigh")
dt.hetero[1, age:=34]
dt.hetero[1, name:="alice"]
```

it expects doubles everywhere and therefore I get a warning when I try to input a string:

```
Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(dt.hetero, 1, `:=`(name, "alice")) :
  NAs introduced by coercion
2: In `[.data.table`(dt.hetero, 1, `:=`(name, "alice")) :
  Coerced 'character' RHS to 'double' to match the column's type. Either change the target column to 'character' first (by creating a new 'character' vector length 3 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'double' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.
dt.hetero[1, name:="alice"]
```

**Edit:**

I get users data sequentially. Thus, the process is

> for every user:
>
> - get user data
> - copy user data to row in data.table
>
> return data.table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can directly specify the type of each column when creating your empty data.table :

```
dt.hetero <- data.table(name = character(3L), 
                        lastname = character(3L), 
                        city = character(3L), 
                        age = integer(3L), 
                        weight = double(3L), 
                        height = double(3L))
```

You can change the number "3" by the number of rows you actually want.

Comment: Thanks Gwenaël! Why do you need to specify 3L instead of 3?

Comment: You don't need to at least not here, it's a habit. The L forces the preceding number to be an integer, in some cases the risk of interpreting this number as numeric or double was giving back an error.

Answer (score 3):

> I need to fill the table row by row.

If you are doing it manually, consider...

```
res <- fread("
  name              age        weight
  Bob               101        111
  Alice             33         77     ")
```

or...

```
rows <- list(
  list(name = "Bob"    , age = 101, weight = 111 ),
  list(name = "Alice"  , age = 33 , weight = 77  ) 
)

res2 <- rbindlist(rows)
```

This second approach can also be used if you are acquiring data sequentially:

```
rows <- vector("list",3)

rows[[1]] <- list(name = "Bob"    , age = 101, weight = 111 )
rows[[2]] <- list(name = "Alice"  , age = 33 , weight = 77  ) 
rows[[3]] <- list(name = "Cadmus" , age = 44 , weight = 55  ) 

res2 <- rbindlist(rows)
```

Obviously, this also works in a loop:

```
for (i in seq_along(rows)){
  # ... do_stuff to find row info ...
  rows[[i]] <- # put row info here
}
res2 <- rbindlist(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks Frank! But I get the data sequentially as well, see edit. Sorry for not thinking that was relevant!

Comment: @alberto Np. You can fill in a list sequentially; I've made an edit to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really slow way of working in R - see ["Second Circle"](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) of R Inferno.  You're much more efficient to 'vectorise' the process:

```
users = c('John','Jill','James')
ages = c(25,53,37)

# of course there is: data.frame(user = users, age=ages), but assuming that's
# not possible in this case..

users_list <- lapply(1:3, FUN=function(i){
  return(data.frame(user = users[i],
                    age = ages[i]))
})

do.call('rbind', users_list)
user age
1  John  25
2  Jill  53
3 James  37
```

Comment: Thanks @geotheory! However I can't use it since I get the information sequentially, I don't have the vectors in your first two lines.

Comment: How are you getting the data that creates the rows line-by-line?

Comment: The real scenario is: I have a database with posts, threads, and users of a forum (e.g. SE, reddit...). For every thread, I build its graph of posts, take some metrics for every post (depth, replies, etc) and fill a row with this information (one per post).

Comment: Then probably best just create a new row with same structure and combine with `rbind`